# How to combine import statements with an import all statement in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, import

I've the following `import` statements using Typescript:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { MouseEvent } from 'react'
```

Typescript complains that I should combine these multiple imports. I've tried the following, but that `MouseEvent` being imported is different:

```
import MouseEvent, * as React from 'react'
```

In this combined import statement, the `MouseEvent` is different from the one imported through `import { MouseEvent } from 'react'`.

For some reason, Typescript recognises that the `MouseEvent` in `import { MouseEvent } from 'react'`accepts type generics but the `MouseEvent` in `import MouseEvent, * as React from 'react'` doesn't.

How can I combine the import statements while still keeping the `MouseEvent` which has generics?

Comment: Please, don't describe error message but quote it precisely. It will help other readers to find this question. I'm positive it isn't TypeScript but TSLint error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TypeScript cannot complain about these import statements because they are correct. It is TSLint that can complain about them and cause an error.

There's no way to shorten them to one line. A common way to do this is to use default export that React also provides:

```
import React, { MouseEvent } from 'react'
```

A downside is that the package is imported entirely into the bundle and cannot make use of tree shaking.

A safe way to do this is:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { MouseEvent } from 'react'
```

In case this causes TSLint error, respective rule needs to be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

When you’re using `import * as React from 'react'`, you import the whole module into a single variable called `React`. Therefore, you can access `MouseEvent` via the `React` namespace: `React.MouseEvent`. As you have already imported everything into a single variable, you can’t import something specific in addition.